Does a publication similar to the American Mathematical Monthly exist in Theoretical Computer Science?
I'm a math major who's been reading up on computational theory and automata theory and I think that I would love to learn more about these and other sub-fields in Theoretical CS.
I'm pretty sure the journal is well known, but in math, there's this journal called the American Mathematical Monthly that prides itself on articles that students with a solid background in freshmen and sophomore math can grasp with some extra reading. This doesn't mean that the papers are outright trivial or prove some undergraduate toy problem, on the contrary, some papers can be quite advanced and niche written by some leading mathematicians. However, the point of the article is exposition and exploration of a few elementary, ideally, novel results. So, the motivation behind each proof is explained a bit more generously than a normal paper, you get discussions of the history behind each problem, and the authors present "what-next" and "so-what" of the results much more explicitly.
I'm looking for a publication similar to the Monthly but focused on Theoretical Computer Science. Specifically, I'm looking for a journal that caters to a wide audience, from advanced undergraduates to professionals. This publication ideally would prioritize exposition and exploration rather than solely presenting results, compared to say the more esoteric and terse professional journals in the field. Thank you for any suggestions!

I have three suggestions:

the Bullettin of the European Association for Theoretical Computer Science, publically available
the SIGACT News, available through ACM's Digital Library
the Communications of the ACM, publically available

The first two are newsletter-type journals to keep the wider TCS community informed. They are not explicitly targeted at students, but they are more focused on exposition than specialized journals and could be first-order approximations to what you seek.
Communications is more broadly aimed at Computer Scientists, so it is less mathematical, but it nevertheless often features theory-oriented overviews of topics.

Communications recently changed to open access. This includes papers from the past!
